# how do I stop reconnect facebook spam?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

I don't mind getting an email from facebook about an event a friend puts on. Or a message they send me.

What bothers me are the "Reconnect with your friends" emails.

how do I stop them but not stop others?

Also the "Getting back into facebook"
"Welcome back to facebook"
funnily enough I only signed in to look for an option to stop the spam and they sent me those other two emails!

Answer (score 1):

The email settings for what gets sent to you are under the notifications tab of the Account Settings page (Top right Account dropdown -> Account Settings)

In the notifications tab, under "View settings for" there are is a link, "Other updates from facebook," you may want to start there.

Comment: I want to know precisely how to stop these emails and not those emails. As I specified.